# str() で文字列にした Python のオブジェクトが json.loads で戻せない

Tags: python, json

python、jsonともにあまり使ったことがないので基本的な理解が抜けている可能性が高いのですが。。。

test.json

```
{
    "book1":{
    "title":"Python Beginners",
    "year": 2005 ,
    "page": 399 
    }
}
```

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import json
f = open("test.json", 'r')
json_data = json.load(f)
json_str = str(json_data)
jj = json.loads(json_str)
print (jj)
```

とやってるんですが、 json.loads のところで以下のエラーが出ます。
なぜでしょうか？

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

ググりまくったのですがもう疲れました。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

端的に言うと、JSON文字列にしたい場合は `str` ではなく、`json.dumps` を使えばよいです。以下詳細。

#### JSONのプロパティ名はダブルクォートで囲まれている必要がある

まず、JSONの表記はPythonのリテラルのような柔軟性はないので、Pythonのリテラルが（あるいはJavaScriptのリテラルであっても）必ずしもJSONとして有効ではないということに注意してください。

```
>>> json.loads('{"a": 123}')   # これはOK
{'a': 123}
>>> json.loads("{'a': 123}")   # これはエラー
# 略
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

上の例ではプロパティ名 `a` をシングルクォートで囲うとエラーになっています。

#### `json.load` はPythonのオブジェクト（辞書）を返す

[`json.load`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/json.html#json.load)の戻り値である `json_data` はPythonのオブジェクト（辞書）です。

```
>>> import json
>>> f = open("test.json", 'r')
>>> json_data = json.load(f)
>>> type(json_data)
<class 'dict'>
>>> json_data
{'book1': {'title': 'Python Beginners', 'year': 2005, 'page': 399}}
```

#### Pythonの辞書の `str` による文字列表現では、キー名がシングルクォートで囲われる

辞書である `json_data` を [`str`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) に与えると、辞書の文字列表現が得られます。

```
>>> str(json_data)
"{'book1': {'title': 'Python Beginners', 'year': 2005, 'page': 399}}"
```

この文字列はJSONとしては不正です。プロパティ名が `'book1'` のように、シングルクォートで囲まれているからです。
ですから、これを `json.loads` に与えると、質問のようなエラーになります。

#### PythonのオブジェクトをJSON文字列にするには `json.dumps` などを使う

上で見たように、`str` が返すのは必ずしもJSONとして有効な文字列ではありません。
ですから、JSON文字列が必要な場合は[`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/json.html#json.dumps)などを使用します。

```
>>> json_str = json.dumps(json_data)
>>> jj = json.loads(json_str)
>>> print (jj)
{'book1': {'title': 'Python Beginners', 'year': 2005, 'page': 399}}
```

Comment: json.loadsが文字列を受け取る、ということで、じゃあ str() を使えばOK!で思考停止してました。たしかに出力を見返すとシングルクォートで出てますね。理解できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score -2):

```
# import json lib
import json

# load json
data = json.load(open('data.json'))

# print content
print(data)

# access a element
print(data['book1'])

# assess a element in a element
print(data['book1']['title'])

# looping over a list
for x in data:
  print(data[x]['title'])
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve the problem. OP asks how to use json.load**s**, not json.load. Moreover, Q&A here must be written in Japanese.　／　これは問題を解決していません。質問者は json.load ではなく json.load**s** をどう使うか質問しています。また、ここでの Q&A は日本語で書かれていないといけません。